# Pros and cons of CSS formatting

Tags: css, code-formatting

Pros and cons of CSS formatting

I know four kinds of CSS formatting.
Which do you think are better?

**A) classic**

```
.class1 {
}
.class1 .class2 {
}
.class1 .class2 .class3 {
}
.classFoo {
}
```

**B) classic idented**

```
.class1 {
}
    .class1 .class2 {
    }
        .class1 .class2 .class3 {
        }
.classFoo {
}
```

**C) same line**

```
.class1 {}
.class1 .class2 {}
.class1 .class2 .class3 {}
.classFoo {}
```

**D) same line idented**

```
.class1 {}
    .class1 .class2 {}
        .class1 .class2 .class3 {}
.classFoo {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I honestly don't think it makes a difference what style you use, so long as you use it consistently *and* it was agreed with anyone else who is likely to work with you on the same projects *and* according to any specific documentation requirements imposed by your work-place/office.

Having said that, my preference is for style A, with groups organised roughly by descent:

```
.className {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    /* ...etc... */
}

.className .descendantOne {
    /* ...stuff... */
}

.className .descendantTwo {
    /* ...stuff... */
}

.anotherClassName {
    /* ...stuff... */
}
```

Having said that, other people have other, valid, preferences.

Obviously, for production code it's more efficient to serve minified code, so the one-line format is closer to what I use once development is complete.

Answer (score 1):

For a huge stylesheet, B since it's easier to navigate because of all the tabbing. ( Using something like SASS reinforces this ).

For a very minimal one, A.

C and D I wouldn't recommend because it's harder to read/manipulate the properties and values. I think the only case for this would be if you were rushing to fix something and didn't care about indenting, otherwise I don't see a benefit.

Of course for production you can opt with a minimized version, so my opinions reflect the one being edited.

Answer (score 0):

you usually only see indentation if it is css generated by sass or less. If you aren't using sass (which you should if you can), it is basically a question of a vs c. c makes sense when you only have a single setting for a rule, a makes sense for when you have more then that.

Answer (score 0):

**Pros:**

- Very easy to navigate and find properties quickly
- Easier to understand when repositioning elements

**Cons:**

- Larger file size (due to extra tabs/spaces) which in turn loads slower
- Other people may be unfamiliar with your formatting (but I wouldn't worry about that much)

Comment: pros and cros of which kind? A, B, C or D?